# Open a firefox new tab in reader view

Tags: firefox, shortcuts

I'm using Firefox  and I like to use the distraction-free "reader view" when I'm reading some text.

My current process is right-click on a link, click in "Open in a new tab" and then click on the reader view like in the image below.

[image: firefox reader view]

Now, I want to find some way to open the new tabs in this mode automatically (when the site allows).

I intend to make it automatically, but I'm also open to some shortcut or even a extension, if necessary.

> - Firefox 43.0.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the perfect solution

1. add this extension [**Menu Wizard**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) to your FireFox, and restart the browser.

[image: Steps 2 to 6]

2. open Menu Wizard config page by clicking **"Alt+Shift+M"** on your keyboard or from the right click menu or by typing **about:config-menu** in the address bar.
3. Expand **Main Context Menu**
4. click on the add button (green plus icon)
5. drag a new menu item from the right panel to the position you desire in the menu
6. Click on the Properties of the New Menu Item

[image]

7. set the Title to whatever you like to appear in the menu (e.g. *Open Link in Reading Mode*)
8. paste this code in the Command > **onCommand** field:

   ```
   if (gContextMenu.onLink) {
         var selectedLink = gContextMenu.getLinkURL();
         var URL = "about:reader?url=" + selectedLink;
         var mytab = gBrowser.addTab(URL);
         gBrowser.selectedTab = mytab;
   }
   ```
9. Click Ok button and exit the Menu Wizard config tab

All Done!

[image]

Comment: Just a side note. The solution works like a charm, but the Menu Wizard extension has a advertising system that can be annoying at times.

Comment: after installation you're given the choice to opt in or out (I want to support the developer window) you must'v chosen the green option which enables ads. maybe there's a way to opt out or try reinstalling the extension and chose (don't support) when asked.

Comment: just checked, go to Menu Wizard setting page > gear icon at the top > "Advertisement is enabled" Change status. does that remove the annoyance?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks for the tip. if you can add this information in your answer, i think it'll help others with the same question than me. Help developers accepting the advertisements is a nice behavior, but sometimes this can be really annoying (like in work environment, for example). Thank you for all

Comment: Can we have this functionality in middle mouse click button? If you can tell me some pointers, that would also be great! Thanks :)

Comment: @q126y we can't. at least not with this method. you'll need an extension that allows custom commands for mouse buttons (quick google search returned nothing) anything more complicated than what I mentioned will require writing a new add-on. and I would have done it if I had the knowledge, sorry.

Comment: Update for those who are looking for this solution: The extension doesn't exist anymore and is probably not replaceable

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1316878