# How can I force specific sites' pages into Reader View in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox

In Firefox (Windows, latest version 50+), is there a way to configure it so that specific sites' pages are *automatically* opened in Reader View?

[Firefox's Reader View help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages) didn't yield any results.

**Please note**: I am asking for an *automated* switch to Reader View (not [manual like this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1032191/open-a-firefox-new-tab-in-reader-view)); and the question assumes that the given site fully supports Reader View, so [every page already has the view icon available](https://superuser.com/questions/1113362/is-there-a-way-to-force-enable-reader-view-in-firefox-on-pages-where-the-icon-do)).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a reasonable answer for you, but it's a bit buggy.

Via the [Readability based Reader View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/readability-based-reader-view/) add-on I can get an entire site to switch to Reader mode.

Firstly, although this isn't the official FireFox Reader View it is using the underlying [Readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability/) library:

> This extension enhances the readability of web pages by removing clutter. **It uses Mozilla's Readability library** to provide a similar experience to the one you get when using Firefox.
>
> -- [FAQ](https://webextension.org/listing/chrome-reader-view.html#faq)

Once you've installed it you can actually get an entire site to switch to Reader View via the options.

[image]

There is an 'Automatic Switch' section where you can specify

> a comma-separated list of hostnames or regular expressions to automatically switch to the reader view

For example I chose `mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk` (note a regular URL https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk doesn't work).

On top of that I ticked the 'Link Opening' checkbox that opens the links in the Reader View also in the Reader View. This effectively means I can stay in Reader View for the entire site.

It has a bug/feature where if you use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> it switches back to normal view.

Since you want just a particular page you can use something like:

`mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Abu_Kamil/`

in the options.