# Mozilla Firefox : activate reader view by default whenever possible

Tags: firefox, browser, web, user-interface, user-experience

I really enjoy Mozilla Firefox's Reader Mode, however it requires clicking on the button everytime I open a new page. Is it possible to specify that I want Reader Mode to be active by default whenever I open a new page, maybe even for a set of given websites ?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the suggested answer. That only shows manual ways of forcing reader view. However this is more likely a duplicate of this question: https://superuser.com/q/1159640/41494

Comment: You can see my answer there: https://superuser.com/a/1762874/41494